# Hiding tab number in a caption (tabular environment)

Tags: tables, captions

Is there a way to hide the Tab number before the caption? (in the following example I'm referring to "Table 2.1:"
[image]

This is my code:

```
    \begin{document}
{\setstretch{1.0}
\begin{table}
\small
\begin{tabular}{ccc} \toprule
\label{TabRochette}
    {\textsc{matrix semantic class}} &  {\textsc{complement semantic class}} & {\textsc{complement syntax}} \\\midrule
    {\textsc{effective}} &  {\textsc{action}} &  {\textsc{VP}}\\
     {\textsc{emotive}} &  {\textsc{event}} &  {\textsc{Infl}}\\
      {\textsc{propositional}} &  {\textsc{propositional}} &  {\textsc{CP}}\\
     \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{\cite{Rochette1999}'s selectional embedding system.}
\end{table}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: If you intend to cross-reference this table using the `\label`-`\ref` method, you should place `\label` after, not before, `\caption`. Seeing that you don't want to number the caption, you probably do *not* intend to cross-reference it elsewhere in the document. Hence, just omit the `\label` statement entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask,

> Is there a way to hide the Tab number before the caption?

By "hide the Tab number", I will assume you mean "suppress the prefix string 'Table 2.1:' ".

Short answer: Yes.

Slightly longer answer: I suggest you load the [caption](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package and replace

```
\caption{\cite{Rochette1999}'s selectional embedding system.}
```

with

```
\caption*{\cite{Rochette1999}'s selectional embedding system.}
```

Put more succinctly: Use `\caption*` instead of `\caption`.

---

The code employed in the table cells of the code snippet you posted is needlessly complicated. Since all cells in all columns employ small-caps, it would make sense to automate this process, along the lines shown in the following example. Not only does the code become easier to read, it'll be easier to debug and modify if and when needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{caption}  % for '\caption*' macro
\usepackage{array}    % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{z}{>{\scshape}c} % use small caps automatically

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small
\centering % <-- don't forget this directive

\begin{tabular}{@{} zzz @{}} 
\toprule
Matrix semantic class & Complement semantic class & Complement syntax \\ 
\midrule
effective & action & VP \\
emotive & event & Infl \\
propositional & propositional & CP \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption*{Your caption.}
%\label{TabRochette} % not meaningful, as there's no table number to cross-reference

\end{table}

\end{document}
```